# Cleveref in section's name does not work in book header

Tags: header-footer, cleveref, books, section-titles

I have a book format document with a theorem's reference in one of the section names. I use `cleveref` to make this reference, it shows perfectly in the section's name and even the table of contents, but in the header it only shows `??`. My MWE is included below.

[image: MWE rendered document]

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]

\begin{theorem}
\label{thm}
Theorem.
\end{theorem}

\section{Proof of \Cref{thm}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If your document has just one such cross-referencing issue, a quick-and-not-too-dirty solution consists of replacing `\section{Proof of \Cref{thm}}` with `\section[Proof of Theorem 1]{Proof of \Cref{thm}}`, where "1" should  be replaced with the actual number.